# Seeking Leaflet printing library that is flexible (not browser print)

Tags: leaflet, software-recommendations, printing, leaflet-plugins

I'm a junior developer and I've been tasked with updating the leaflet part of the website.

Do you know a good printing library where I could just export the map shown on the screen and manipulate it a bit before printing it?

We're using some homebrewed code with Leaflet image and it’s far from optimal(there's cropping and aspect ratio problems). I read a bit about bigImage and I'd like to know if it’s a good option.

Answer (score 3):

Leaflet's plug-in page is located here: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html

They have a few related to printing which you could test and choose from:

[image]

They all have workable demos to test them.

[image]